# How to copy to clipboard without change the fontstyle in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to copy my new generated text with text style in the clipboard but the clipboard just copies the text without the text style.
`IconButton( onPressed: () {Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text));},icon:const Icon(Icons.copy))`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fReOo.png)

Comment: If you press the copy to clipboard just save the entered text and the name of font family in a var

Answer (score 0):

> This data structure currently supports only plain text data, in the text property.

See [ClipboardData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/ClipboardData-class.html) for details.

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem?  I saw some applications that can copy the text to the clipboard with the font style.  for instance: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dricodes.fontgenerator&hl=en&gl=US